# Parsing a pdf without a strong structure

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I want to extract data from a pdf with python, but I cannot solve the parsing problems.

The pdf is quite regular, but the result of the script is not good because:

- some rows are read together
- it does not leave blank space in columns without data

The result of the script is:

```
02001 13 VU Sencilla 100 Normal 125 90 112 200
02001 11 VU Sencilla 50 Normal 160 80 180 30002001 5 VU Media 40 Normal 160 160 280 34002001 12 VU Media 40 Normal 160 160 280 4100
```

It should be:

```
02001 13 VU Sencilla 100 Normal 125 90 112 NULL 200
02001 11 VU Sencilla 50 Normal 160 80 180 NULL 300
02001 5 VU Media 40 Normal 160 160 280 NULL 340
02001 12 VU Media 40 Normal 160 160 280 NULL 410
```

Any help?

This is the script:

```
import PyPDF2

# Ruta del archivo PDF
pdf_file_path = r"C:\Users\ruben\Desktop\DIGITAL\01 BD\04 Data\valref\W7EXZ41H1MW4FMR9.pdf"

# Abrir el archivo PDF en modo de lectura binaria
with open(pdf_file_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    # Crear un objeto de lectura de PDF
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

    # Obtener el número de páginas del PDF
    num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

    with open(r"C:\Users\ruben\Downloads\W7EXZ41H1MW4FMR9.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        for page_num in range(1, num_pages):
            page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
        
            # Skip the last 9 rows on each page
            page_content = page.extract_text().split('\n')[9:-11]
            page_content = '\n'.join(page_content)

            text_file.write(page_content)
            print(f"Contenido de la página {page_num + 1}:")
            print(page_content)
```

[Here you can download the pdf (Spanish Cadastre website)](https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/DocumentosCatalogo/SECRecuperarDocumento.aspx?csv=W7EXZ41H1MW4FMR9)